# Modify JSON during entity denormalisation

Tags: redux, normalizr

During normalisation of JSON, I am able to modify the entities as they are processed. Say, for example, I add a new property to entities during this phase. I can do this by setting a function for `processStrategy`.

What I was wondering was: is there any way to do similar custom processing during the denormalisation phase, as each entity is denormalised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a way to do that during denormalization. The expectation is that you run your processing once during normalization so you won't have to do it again.

Comment: The reason why I asked is because I add custom properties to various objects during normalisation. These properties are only specific to the app. When sending the denormalised JSON back to my API, I want to strip those out. Hence why I thought that it would be nice to be able to do that neatly when denormalising, similarly like when I added them during normalisation.